# Thread blocked after await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

With this code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread Pre - " + GetNativeThreadId(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread));
        Task.Run(() => AsyncMethod()).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread Post - " + GetNativeThreadId(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task AsyncMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncMethod Thread Pre - " + GetNativeThreadId(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread));
        await Task.Delay(4000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("AsyncMethod Thread Post - " + GetNativeThreadId(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread));
    }
```

The output is:

```
Main Thread Pre - 8652
AsyncMethod Thread Pre - 4764
AsyncMethod Thread Post - 1768
Main Thread Post - 8652
```

Using the Concurrency Visualizer, I can see that during the 4 second delay, thread 4764 is stuck in Synchronization.  It is eventually unblocked by the main thread on shutdown.

Shouldn't thread 4764 be returned to the `ThreadPool` once it hits the `await`?  (That being said I don't know what that would look like inside the Concurrency Visualizer)

Comment: Can you demonstrate any sort of problem *without* resorting to the concurrency visualizer?

Comment: No I can't.  I did this as an exercise to see what an awaited thread looked like inside the concurrency visualizer and was surprised to see it sitting in the Synchronization category once it awaits.  Either my understanding of async is incorrect or I'm misinterpreting what the concurrency visualizer is telling me.  I suppose I'm just looking for confirmation that thread 4764 should actually be returned to the ThreadPool when it hits the await.

Comment: The task thread is delayed but the Delay call is still internally running a timer and as such doing work. The delay is not a scheduling delay.

Comment: So would it make sense for 4764 to be blocked until the Delay has completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't thread 4764 be returned to the ThreadPool once it hits the await?

Yes. And it is.

> (That being said I don't know what that would look like inside the Concurrency Visualizer)

That's easy enough to check. Just explicitly execute some code in the thread pool, and take a look at what that thread looks like in the visualizer when it's not busy.

For example:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("worker: " + GetNativeThreadId(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread));
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    });
```

(I added the sleep so it shows up more easily in the visualizer as having done something :) ).

And when you do, you'll see that what it looks like is just like what you see. :)

When I ran this, the thread pool even used the same worker thread that it used for the original `Task`. And you can see that a thread pool worker thread sits in the `Synchronization` state while it's waiting for more work.

Which makes sense. At an abstract level, what's the thread pool doing? The whole point is for it to have threads which already exist. But you don't want those threads actually out there *working* unless they have something to work on. That would burn CPU time for no reason. So instead, they wait on a synchronization object.

When something (like `Task`) wants to use one, it queues a work item, and then the thread pool signals to the thread it's got something to do. This wakes up the thread, it does its work, and then it blocks on the synchronization object again, waiting for something else to do.

If you check the call stack for the relevant threads, you'll see the worker thread waiting on a call to `WaitForSingleObject()`, and you'll see that the thread pool ultimately unblocks the thread using `ReleaseSemaphore()`.

And this shows up as the `Synchronization` state for the thread pool thread, just as you saw.